# Git hooks to fire when using merge with --no-ff

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks

Assume I have two branches:

1. feature
2. master

If I merge feature into master and force a commit merge with `--no-ff` like so:

`git merge feature --no-ff`

Will any of the client side commit hooks (e.g. commit-msg, pre-commit) be fired? I would assume so since with `--no-ff`, we are introducing a commit.

Yet they don't seem to fire for me. What gives? Can someone point me to some documentation?

Comment: The commit-msg hook fires normally for me in that case (using v2.17.1). Does the problem still occur?